# Activating virtualenv in linux isn't working

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've installed `virtualenv` on a Ubuntu 20.04. After sourcing the `activate` script, it seems that it is activated, but installing packages seems to install it in the user's site-packages rather than in the virtual environment.

```
(venv) $ python3 -m pip install pytest
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (6.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pytest) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<2.0,>=0.12 in /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pytest) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.8.2 in /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pytest) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (fro
```

Also, when I run Python and look at the `sys.path`:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Comment: `echo $PATH` ? `type -a python3` ?

Comment: how did you set up your `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab in the dark and say, inside a virtualenv, you probably don't need to invoke `python3` rather, the `python` command directly points to the Python 3 interpreter *for that virtualenv*. And in this instance, invoking `python3` explicitly points to your global Python 3 env. After all, modern virtualenvs are created with Python 3 as default.

Comment: To add to this, running `which python` and `which python3` will allow you to confirm the above, both before and after activating the virtual environment.

Comment: To add to that, you can also run `pip --version` after activating your env to see where the pip resides. If it is in your env folder you are good to go. And when creating the env, you can do `python=python3` to specify which python version you want to use. Inside, you just use `python` to run python code.